# qTranslate-X messes theme CSS in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, qtranslate

I just added the qTranslate plugin to my WordPress site, but now, when I switch to another language in the menu, the CSS colors from the menu and buttons return to default. (Only in the new languages)

http://www.gasolina.me

Further inspection on the elements shows me that the browser is looking for the css (selection.php) inside the /es/ or /fr/ directories, but since its not there, the colors revert to the default, from another CSS file.

All the other CSS are fine (downloaded from the correct location), its only selection.php

I tried manually adding the file in a NEW /es/ directory but it messes the home page and displays an error when I add that directory.

The file marked as "initiator" (in my browser inspector) for the CSS file is not calling the /es/ directory in the href link for the php CSS file. So I don't know where to fix the mistake. Since all the other CSS files that are called from that same file are not being looked for inside the language directory.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution was to add the php extension to the qTranslate ignore links settings inside the advanced settings. So that php files don't get translated (or their address location, rather)